# Why doesn't ListView.EnsureVisible() work?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm trying to make an app that supports Multi-Threading. It has several different Tabs and I have one tab with a log of every initialized operation. when I update my log I want it to scroll to the bottom. I'm using the `ListView` control.

```vb
Public Sub SubmitLog(ByVal Data As String)

  If Data <> "" Then
    With lstLogs
      .Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String(1) {Date.Now.ToString(), Data}))
      .Items.Item(.Items.Count - 1).EnsureVisible()
    End With
  End If

End Sub
```

To test it I call a simple loop:

```vb
 For I As Integer = 0 To 50
   SubmitLog(Path.GetRandomFileName())
 Next
```

But it does not scroll to the last item. Why isn't it scrolling to the bottom and how can I make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `Selected` property to true:

```
If Data <> "" Then
  With lstLogs
    .Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String(1) {Date.Now.ToString(), Data}))
    .Items.Item(.Items.Count - 1).Selected = True
    .Items.Item(.Items.Count - 1).EnsureVisible()
  End With
End If
```

or just make sure the `lstLogs` control has focus.

Discussed here: [Problem with Listview EnsureVisible](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=506408)